# Jquery:Bootstrap form validation library not working on dynamiclly added elements

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstap validator library for form validation.

```
  //validate when submit button is clicked.
    $('#passenger-form').bootstrapValidator({
     fields: {
       email: {
                    group: '.col-xs-6',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Email required'
                        }

                    }
                }
             //rest of the rules here
     }
     });
```

Sometime my form is dynamically added (based on some conditions made by the user) and at that time validation does not work.

When the form is dynamically added the validation rules are not working.
I know `jquery.on` event can be used to solve this issue, but how can I use it in my case?

Comment: I can help you out if you could share the link to your library documentation.

Comment: Here is the library https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator

Comment: Also upgrading the library may give you what you need http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.on may not help you in this context, since you are using a plugin.

Looking at the website for BootrapValidator, it looks like it has been superseded by [FormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/).

Putting that aside, it looks like your best bet would be to create a function that binds the validator, and call that function when you add form elements dynamically.

For example:

```
function bindForm() {
    //validate when submit button is clicked.
    $('#passenger-form').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
            email: {
                group: '.col-xs-6',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Email required'
                    }
                }
            }
            //rest of the rules here
        }
     });
}
//call it by default if the form is present
bindForm();

//call it when a user generates an event
function userGeneratedEvent() {
    //do whatever it is that this event is for
    //add the form as described in the question
    bindForm();
}
```

Comment: @BlessanKurien yes, example added.

Answer (score 1):

`there is no documentation available in the link you provided, I think the plugin is closed.`

Ok so here is the idea. since the dynamically added elements have come into the DOM after the plugin is applied, the plugin has no clue of these elements. You need to re apply the validation plugin when ever you add new dynamic elements. Or better thing would be to not apply the plugin, But on submit of the form catch the form submit event, and then apply the plugin. This must be simpler without more overheads.